# Android can't connect to a Google Cloud Server using JSch

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, jsch

I'm struggling already for a few days with a connection issue using JSch in Android app.

At First, I tried using user & password but got `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail`
Here is the code I used for:

```
try {
    String command = "ls -la";
    String hostname = "host_ip";
    String user = "xxxxx";
    String password = "yyyyy";

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, hostname, 22);

    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.connect(30000);

    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
    channel.setInputStream(null);
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

    InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();
    channel.connect();

    System.out.println("Channel Connected to machine " + hostname + " server with command: " + command);

    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then I thought maybe to try use private key instead a password, but not matter where I have placed id_rsa file I got `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: path_to_file/id_rsa (No such file or directory)`
Here is the code:

```
try {
    String command = "ls -la";
    String hostname = "host_ip";
    String user = "xxxxx";
    String password = "yyyyy";

    String privateKey = "path_to_file/id_rsa";

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, hostname, 22);
    session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect(30000);

    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
    channel.setInputStream(null);
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

    InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();
    channel.connect();

    System.out.println("Channel Connected to machine " + hostname + " server with command: " + command);

    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have read a lot of articles and different posts in Stackoverflow but nothing helped. 
Thanks in advance.